# How to list filenames without directory in BASH using find

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating a variable listing all filenames in a directory, for later use in a for loop.

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
images=website/images
dirlist=`find $images -type f`
echo $dirlist
```

$dirlist currently shows all files correctly and can be used in the subsequent for loop, but also contains the directory names:

> website/images/Todiste71.png website/images/Torsion.png website/images/GLP Bewegung Tag 0bis3.gif website/images/Todiste70.png website/images/StanislawSisk.jpg website/images/Hejného metoda graf.jpg website/images/Mathemagicslogo.png website/images/Odddecomp2d.jpg website/images/Fields of Mathematics Ukr.png website/images/Todiste99.png website/images/Todiste72.png website/images/Subdivision rule related to 4-chain alternating link.png website/images/Todiste73.png website/images/Todiste98.png website/images/Todiste88.png website/images/Todiste77.png website/images/Todiste76.png website/images/Todiste89.png website/images/Illustration of the slope of a straight line y=-2x+13.png website/images/Portal Math Banner hy.png website/images/Calculating the slope of the linear equation y=-2x+13 (bold).png website/images/Vingenere 1.png website/images/Todiste74.png website/images/Vertical horizontal.PNG website/images/Curve with tangent line.png website/images/Correlacion.png website/images/Todiste75.png website/images/GradientOfRegularPentagonExteriorAngle.gif website/images/PointToLineDistance v2.png website/images/Sistema anotación alge 005.jpg website/images/Todiste132.png website/images/Todiste126.png website/images/Tree-basis.jpg website/images/1-6 Rossler Skeleton.png website/images/LeibnizInfinitesimalTriangle.png website/images/Calculating the slope of the linear equation y=-2x+13.png website/images/SilverRatioCirclesTangentLine 2.gif website/images/Tangent line versus secant line.png website/images/Histogram sum of length 2 permutations of 1 2 3.svg website/images/Todiste127.png website/images/Todiste133.png website/images/Monodromy action.svg website/images/Todiste125.png website/images/Todiste131.png website/images/Todiste119.png website/images/Mobius shadow.jpg website/images/Rossler Periodic Orbit w2.gif website/images/Todiste118.png website/images/Todiste130.png ...

I need to make the code so that $dirlist just shows images/{filename}, or just the {filename} without the directory names. For instance, the following would be acceptable outputs:

> images/Todiste71.png

> Todiste71.png

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "...subsequent for loop..." -- consider using `-exec progname {} +` or `-exec progname {} \;` instead of a for-loop, as the former are much more stable with regards to "funny" filenames.

Comment: Because I think you need some parts of the directory names (subdirectories in your base folder) for the later loop, you also can do a simple `cd` before the `find` and a `cd - >/dev/null` after the find. It's also possible to eliminate the content of your pathvariable (images) with a sed: `find $images -type f | sed -e "s#^$images/##"`

Comment: @GaryKong : Wouldn't it make more sense to use an Array? It's easier to process than a scalar variable holding all the filenames, and you don't run into problems with spaces in a filename.

Comment: @GaryKong: Removed _sh_ tag, because it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Does [Remove path from find command output](https://serverfault.com/questions/354403/) answer your question?

Comment: I ended up using the solution proposed by gmu (using sed-e to eliminate the content of the pathvariable)

Answer (score 2):

Use [basename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) to remove the directory.

Or use the printf option of [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

```
find "$images" -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! Used basename and it works.