# Looping through files in a directory but the directory name gets echoed twice

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on looping through files in bash script and for the most part it is working but the directory name is echoed twice. How could I change the code to only echo the files in the directory and not the directory itself.

This is my code:

```
Directory=C:/temp/

find $Directory
for filename in "$Directory"/;
do 
    echo $filename
done
```

This is what I see in my terminal:

```
C:/temp/
C:/temp/QJ07312433_10_19_2021_snapshot.xml
C:/temp/QJ07312433_10_28_2021_snapshot.xml
C:/temp/
```

Comment: You're not looping through the results of `find`.

Comment: The directory name is being echoed by `echo $filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` command prints all the names in the hierarchy headed by `$Directory`.  Then you loop through the single string `$Directory/`, and echo that. This is why you get the second echo of the directory name.

If you want the loop to process the `find` output in the loop, you need to pipe to it:

```
find "$Directory" | while read -r name; do
    echo "$name"
done
```

Comment: That gives me 
C:/temp/
C:/temp/QJ07312433_10_19_2021_snapshot.xml
C:/temp/QJ07312433_10_28_2021_snapshot.xml
How would I get just the files echoed and not the name of the directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100407/how-to-list-filenames-without-directory-in-bash-using-find